# PHP MSSQL using date between

Tags: php, t-sql

I'm trying to display some data from MSSQL table. I want to show data about business trip, that were took place over a period of time.

Without date works fine, when I use date I took

> Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\connection\index.php on line 52

Can somebody help me how to fix it.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="user_name">
        <?php while($row1=sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result1)):;?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row1[1]/*." ".$row1[0]>*/?>"><?php echo $row1[1]." ".$row1[0];?></option>                
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="date_od" placeholder="Calendar" name="datum_od"></input>
    <input type="text" id="date_do" placeholder="Calendar" name="datum_do"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="btn">
</form>
```

```
if(isset($_POST['btn'])) { 
    $user_name=$_POST['user_name'];
    $datum_od=$_POST['datum_od']; //I have this format: 2019-01-08
    $datum_do=$_POST['datum_do'];} //I have this format: 2019-01-08

    $sql = "SELECT SURNAME_USER, ID_USER, FIRST_NAME_USER, EVENT_CALENDAR_EVENT.EVENT_NAME,EVENT_DATE_FROM, EVENT_DATE_TO,EVENT_CALENDAR_OBJECT.OBJECT_NAME  FROM XG_USER INNER JOIN EVENT_CALENDAR_EVENT ON ID_USER = EVENT_USER_ID INNER JOIN EVENT_CALENDAR_OBJECT ON OBJECT_CAL_ID = ID_CAL_OBJECT WHERE ID_USER IN (SELECT EVENT_USER_ID FROM EVENT_CALENDAR_EVENT) AND and EVENT_DATE_FROM >= '$datum_od' AND EVENT_DATE_TO <= '$datum_do' AND SURNAME_USER LIKE '$user_name' and OBJECT_NAME IS NOT NULL";


    $result2 = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
?>
<table>
    <t>
        <th>Jméno</th>
        <th>Přijmení</th>
        <th>Událost</th>
    </t>
    <?php 
        while ($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result2)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $rows["FIRST_NAME_USER"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows["SURNAME_USER"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows["EVENT_NAME"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows["OBJECT_NAME"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows["EVENT_DATE_FROM"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows["EVENT_DATE_TO"];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: I highly suggest you learn how to use prepared/parametrised statements. What you have above is very open to injection.

Comment: I know, is only for internal use - only for 2 person.

Comment: That isn't an excuse for poor programming practices. There is never an excuse to write code with such basic security flaws, unless you're using it to demonstrate just how huge a flaw it is, and why it can be so easily avoided.